# How can I get compile-time validation of literals in IsString instances?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I would like to be able to make `IsString` instances using the GHC `OverloadedStrings` extension such that my instance rejects some literals as being invalid and such that that rejection happens at compile time, so that programming mistakes don't make it into the code I give to my users.

I have a couple of use cases where I have a `Name` type that only admits certain strings. e.g.

```
module Name (Name(getName), makeName) where

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as Text

-- | A guaranteed non-empty name.
newtype Name = Name { getName :: Text } deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

makeName :: Text -> Maybe Name
makeName name
  | Text.null name = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just name
```

In a real use case, I'd check for valid characters, not starting with a digit, that sort of thing.

The idea is that we don't export the `Name` constructor, which means anyone using a `Name` value can trust that it has certain properties (in this case, non-empty).

My problem is that I'd like to use literal names in many places. e.g.

```
programName :: Name
programName = fromJust $ makeName "the-great-and-powerful-turtle"
```

Because I do this a lot, I've defined an `unsafeMakeName` helper that does pretty much the same thing:

```
unsafeMakeName :: Text -> Name
unsafeMakeName name = fromMaybe (error $ "Invalid name: " <> Text.unpack name) (makeName name)
```

The problem with this approach is that even though the cause of the mistake is a programming error, I don't find out about it until run time.

What I'd like to do is write an `IsString` instance for `Name` which does that validation, e.g.

```
instance IsString Name where
  fromString = unsafeMakeName . Text.pack
```

... but to get the error about invalid names in literals at compile-time.

When I try this, I only seem to get the errors at run-time, when the literal value is used. This is less than ideal, since it's an error in my actual code.

Is there any way I can do this? Is this something that could be remedied in GHC? Note that I've already [filed a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13028) there.

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to use Template Haskell to do the validation via compile-time splice.

Comment: For something heavy weight, you could try to use liquid-haskell's totality checker.  At the very least it would be fun.

Comment: This would be great for `printf` and its format string, for instance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It really sounds like what you want is a [quasiquoter](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#template-haskell-quasi-quotation) and not `OverloadedStrings`. The validation logic then goes inside the [`Q`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Q) monad, which runs at compile time. For your simple example above:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell #-}

module Name (Name(getName), name) where

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as Text

import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote hiding (Name)
import Language.Haskell.TH hiding (Name)

-- | A guaranteed non-empty name.
newtype Name = Name { getName :: Text } deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

makeName :: String -> Q Exp
makeName name
  | null name = fail "Invalid name"
  | otherwise = [| Name (Text.pack name) |]

name :: QuasiQuoter
name = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp = makeName }
```

Then, in another module, the following compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Name

main = print [name|valid-name|]
```

But the following doesn't, and spits out the `Invalid name` error message.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Name

main = print [name||]
```

Note that you can get quasiquoters that work for patterns too (so something like `myFunc [name|valid-name|] = True` could be a valid function definition)!